# How to have php vardump and twig dump work properly without XDebug extension activated?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, xdebug, var-dump

I am using PHP Symfony 2 with Twig. Could be relevant to pure PHP.

For performance reasons with WAMP + Windows 7, I have deactivated the XDebug extension. Now my pages loads faster.

However, this comes with var dumping issues.

The nice format of the php var_dump has disappeared. I have installed REF and I can get something similar with `~r($myvariable)`.

However the twig `{{ dump(myvariable) }}` does not work anymore, I get a complete blank screen though I did verify on the php side that `myvariable` was valid.

How can I have the `var_dump` work properly in both PHP and twig without XDebug being installed?

Comment: Does standard `var_dump()` work in pure php after installing `REF`?

Comment: it does work but the format is ugly. It's all condensed, no colors, no indentation. and it's not limited to 3 levels so it gets to load a lot of ressources

Comment: Twig's `dump()` just uses standard `var_dump`. And if it works in pure PHP it must work in Twig.

Comment: hmmm, I realize it might be because there is no 3 level dumping limitation that it somehow bugs. If I'm dumping an entity with many associations, it's very long in php, it might just crash with twig. I'm gonna try with something simpler.

Comment: yeah, it does work with a simple variable! thanks!

Comment: You may try https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle

Comment: wow, this ladybug thing is nice!

Comment: @Maerlyn: do you know how to set the default options beyond what's shown in the doc and according to waht's available here https://github.com/franmomu/Ladybug/blob/master/lib/Ladybug/Options.php ? would be nice to tweak that directly in the config.yml file

Comment: Nope, I never used it, just knew it existed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html `<pre>` tag to achive this easily.

> The HTML `<pre>` Element (or HTML Preformatted Text) represents
>   preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in
>   a non-proportional font exactly as it is laid out in the file.
>   Whitespaces inside this element are displayed as typed.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

Your code will look as follows:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($variable);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is caused by `var_dump` dumping the entire object: if the object has many associations, it takes very long for php to display the result and it just crashed with twig.

My short term solution : no `var_dump` of object

My mid-term solution : implement a twig filter for REF.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the output is nicer with XDebug (when html_errors is on), however if you've disabled extension, you can add a `pre` tag, e.g.

```
<pre>
    {{ dump(user) }}
</pre>
```

or to show all variables, use just `<pre> {{ dump() }} </pre>`. Alternatively check the code source, so new line endings can be shown properly.

Note that the dump function is not available by default, so you must add the `Twig_Extension_Debug` extension explicitly when creating your Twig environment:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'debug' => true,
    // ...
));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

otherwise `dump` function won't display anything if the debug option on the environment is not enabled.

If you still have a blank page, enable PHP error reporting and displaying them on the page, or check PHP error log for any clues.

See: [Functions » dump](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html)